# Way to speed up binary sampling in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, sampling

I have a vector of solutions that varies in length, but can be up to 1500 numbers. I want to sample x solutions at a time, which I later run some matrix calculations on. The issue I'm running into is that R is very slow to create a matrix of binary samples, even when I pre-allocate the variable. Is there a more efficient way to create the matrix below?

```
all_sol <- rnorm(1500)
sol_num <- length(all_sol)
startran <- 10*nrow(all_sol)
nlin <- 20
initguess <- data.frame(matrix(rep(0, sol_num * startran), 
                               nrow = startran, ncol = sol_num))

for(i in 1:startran){
  # get indices to replace
  samp = sample.int(sol_num, size = nlin)
  
  # set new values
  initguess[i, samp] =  1
}
initguess <- as.matrix(initguess, nrow = startran, ncol = sol_num)
```

Comment: 1) With the code in the question, `nrow(all_sol)` returns `NULL` since `all_sol` does not have the `dim` attribute set. 2) If the data is numeric (binary) work with matrices they are faster than data.frames. 3) To sample binary numbers, see `help("rbinom")`. 4) Continuing point 3, why coerce to df and when the data is populated with 1's, coerce back to matrix? Remove both the `as.data.frame` and the last instruction.

Comment: Also, after its creation, what does `dim(initguess)` return?

Comment: Setting `sol_num <- 1500` and `startran <- 10*1500` your code takes about 10 to 12 seconds on my 4 to 50 years old laptop. What are your expectations, how fast this should get?